# Robotium Test cases for Android

Tags: android, robotium

All.. I am new to JUnit TestCases. I want  to write junit test cases on android .apk ,with out using source code. Because i don't have source code.

Please Provoke me.
 Thank for ur Help in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Robotium is used for black-box testing.

I assume you are new to Robotium, in that case, refer to the [Getting Started](http://code.google.com/p/robotium/wiki/Getting_Started) page,

And the [Test Android APK File With Robotium](http://robotium.googlecode.com/files/RobotiumForBeginners.pdf) Tutorial.

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite for testing .apk file w/o source code 
 - package name
 - its starting activity class name
 - signature (.keystore) file of the target .apk file

Steps : 
 1. Read the docs at http://robotium.googlecode.com/files/RobotiumForBeginners.pdf
 2. In your AndroidTestProject make sure you add the .keystore file
        In eclipse goto Window->Preferences->Android->Build->Custom debug keystore 
 3. Make sure the target packages and starting intent activity files are replaced.
 4. In the AndroidManifest.xml file specify the targetPackage as same as target package.